# Solidity assembly function returns false on forked blockchain

Tags: solidity, assembly, multisignature, calldata, forks

I try to **simulate** submitting transaction to `Multisig` contract and confirming transaction by other multisig members by *impersonating their account* on Hardhat with forking.

I managed submitting and confirming transaction on fork localhost. After enough confirmation, executing function is triggered. But, it isn't executed successfully, `ExecutionFailure(transactionId)` event is triggered when I check. It means that `external_call` function returns `false`. (You can check the functions below)

However, I tried to call only `external_call` with giving the function's input parameters manually on Remix, to check if it gives `false` as well. But, it gives `true` on Remix (without forking, for sure)

**In summary,** the function returns false on forking localhost, returns true on localhost when I put input parameters manually.

`call_data` function includes **assembly operations** which I don't know very well. So, I couldn't manage to find the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Multisig: https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit.sol

1. Call the `submitTransaction` of Multisig with my account.

   ```solidity
   /// @dev Allows an owner to submit and confirm a transaction.
   /// @param destination Transaction target address.
   /// @param value Transaction ether value.
   /// @param data Transaction data payload.
   /// @return Returns transaction ID.
   function submitTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes data)
       public
       returns (uint transactionId)
   {
       transactionId = addTransaction(destination, value, data);
       confirmTransaction(transactionId);
   }
   ```
2. Other multi-sig members call `confirmTransaction`.

```solidity
    /// @dev Allows an owner to confirm a transaction.
    /// @param transactionId Transaction ID.
    function confirmTransaction(uint transactionId)
        public
        ownerExists(msg.sender)
        transactionExists(transactionId)
        notConfirmed(transactionId, msg.sender)
    {
        confirmations[transactionId][msg.sender] = true;
        Confirmation(msg.sender, transactionId);
        executeTransaction(transactionId);
    }
```

3. When it reaches enough confirmation, `executeTransaction` is called internally. It calls `external_call` function finally.

```solidity
    /// @dev Allows anyone to execute a confirmed transaction.
    /// @param transactionId Transaction ID.
    function executeTransaction(uint transactionId)
        public
        ownerExists(msg.sender)
        confirmed(transactionId, msg.sender)
        notExecuted(transactionId)
    {
        if (isConfirmed(transactionId)) {
            Transaction storage txn = transactions[transactionId];
            txn.executed = true;
            if (external_call(txn.destination, txn.value, txn.data.length, txn.data))
                Execution(transactionId);
            else {
                ExecutionFailure(transactionId);
                txn.executed = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // call has been separated into its own function in order to take advantage
    // of the Solidity's code generator to produce a loop that copies tx.data into memory.
    function external_call(address destination, uint value, uint dataLength, bytes data) internal returns (bool) {
        bool result;
        assembly {
            let x := mload(0x40)   // "Allocate" memory for output (0x40 is where "free memory" pointer is stored by convention)
            let d := add(data, 32) // First 32 bytes are the padded length of data, so exclude that
            result := call(
                sub(gas, 34710),   // 34710 is the value that solidity is currently emitting
                                   // It includes callGas (700) + callVeryLow (3, to pay for SUB) + callValueTransferGas (9000) +
                                   // callNewAccountGas (25000, in case the destination address does not exist and needs creating)
                destination,
                value,
                d,
                dataLength,        // Size of the input (in bytes) - this is what fixes the padding problem
                x,
                0                  // Output is ignored, therefore the output size is zero
            )
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What does the failing function is trying to do? The type of multisig contract has been working for several years without issues. I doubt the problem is in the multisig, it is more likely in the function you are trying to execute.

Comment: Failing function is trying to queue transaction on timelock contract. To note that, if I impersonate the multisig contract on forked chain, it successfully works.

Comment: There isn't enough information to reproduce the issue. If you don't want to provide the code used try recreating a minimal reproducible example.